# System service cannot access internet

Tags: windows, networking, active-directory, group-policy, gpo

I have a service running as LocalSystem, starting a simple program that polls a https endpoint that is hosted outside the local network. The system that the poll program is running on is connected to a domain, and is managed by an active directory controller. While a domain user is signed into the system the web requests are sent perfectly fine, however once the user signs out the web requests are no longer sent, even though the program is still running in the background of the logon screen. The cause is loss of network connectivity.

This appears to be caused some form of authentication issue, where the computer is allowed to access network resources when authenticated as a user, however when no user is signed in, it is not allowed access, probably being restricted to only sending authentication requests rather than having wider network access.

I am simply wondering if anyone could provide all the group policies that may cause this type of problem, so I can alter them, thanks.

Comment: In almost all cases, it is preferable to have a dedicated domain user running the service instead of mucking with LocalSystem. It will allow you to tailor required local privileges without compromising restrictions to LocalSystem that are there for good reasons.

Answer (score 0):

•   As per your condition, firstly you should the check the web application’s virtual directory permissions whether authentication for required users is allowed or not. Secondly, please check whether integrated windows authentication or an application specific service account is configured for sending requests from the web application because if integrated windows authentication is configured for a domain user account, then only when a domain user account signs into the system, the service dependent on the web application will be able to send the web requests else the web requests won’t be sent.

•   Please find the below group policies to be checked as requested by you: -

Computer Configuration  Windows Settings  Security Settings  Local Policies  User Rights Assignments  Logon as a service

Computer Configuration  Windows Settings  Security Settings  Local Policies  User Rights Assignments  Logon locally

Computer Configuration  Windows Settings  Security Settings  Local Policies  User Rights Assignments  Access this computer from the network

Computer Configuration  Windows Settings  Security Settings  Local Policies  User Rights Assignments  Deny logon locally

Computer Configuration  Administrative Templates  Network  Windows Connection Manager  Prohibit connection to non-domain networks when connected to domain authenticated network

Computer Configuration  Administrative Templates  Network  Windows Connection Manager  Enable Windows to soft-disconnect a computer from a network

•   Please refer the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/security-policy-settings